# Why does my heater have a weak flame after restarting?

Tags: heater

I have a Intertherm M1M It runs great one time then gives a weak flame (after the flame goes out) after reaching temp. I changed the igniter/temp sensor (one unit). I replaced the main board also. Still the same problem.

Could it be the thermostat?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The thermostat should turn the system on and off. If you are having problems with intermittent flame you may have moisture in your line. I usually install drip legs after the shutoff valve prior to the furnace, water heater or range this traps the water. A drip leg is a T with a short section of pipe going straight down that is capped. This leg catches rust, and moisture. 1 drop of water in a gas valve can cause problems so I would check to see if you have a drip leg and if so shut the gas off and clean it. If you don't install one. I have had homes that had horrible moisture problems in gas lines and others that had almost no problems. Since you have thrown all those parts at it I would be looking at moisture as the possible cause.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're experienced in gas heater repairs I suggest to contact a professional service technician. Usually your gas service provider has trained techs on staff.

Here is [the schematic](http://www.nortekhvac.com/literature/690a.pdf) with trouble shooting assistance for the model posted. Hopefully this PDF opens for you. If not, Google search your model with troubleshooting after it in the search bar...